# Menu margin after the navbar collapse Bootstrap 4

Tags: css

I have a menu on the navbar that have a certain margin-top and a certain margin-right, when the navbar collapse I want that the menu have margin-top = 20px without affecting the margin-top when the navbar is not collpase (it shoudl return to the normal margin-top as it was before).

Comment: Please click edit and paste your code into the question, then format it. We need a place to start from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it sounds like one of the ways you can do this is with a css media query,but as someone said, please share the code.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
     li.menu {
     margin-top: 20px;
  }
}
```

Where the max-width is set to what you want, and "li.menu" is targeting the element you wish to change the margin of.

Don't forget to add the viewport meta tag to your head as well for media queries to work.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Also make sure if you aren't using an ID or a class specific to that menu item only, that the media query is placed below your normal menu styling, otherwise it will be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in javascript or you can use css. When the menu is collapse it's because we are on smaller screen like a Phone. You can duplicate you menu and hide one  when it's collapsed with you margin.

Or Second option best option. use media query to do it when you are on certain screen